# Mongoose and socket.io two connections

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I am using  [socket.io-adapter-mongo](https://github.com/modit/socket.io-adapter-mongo) to make it possible to create balance loader in my app.  In addition to that I want to use mongoose to manage db. If I use the api that the two packages give is

#### socket.io-adapter-mongo

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var mongo = require('socket.io-adapter-mongo');
io.adapter(mongo({ host: 'localhost', port: 27017, db: 'mubsub' }));
```

#### mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
```

So if I want to use both of them, do I have to connect to the db twice?
Or that is a way to use them with one connection?

Thanks

Comment: Does your app works on different servers?

Answer (score 2):

The below code will work

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { createAdapter } = require("@socket.io/mongo-adapter")

const collection = mongoose.connection.createCollection("chatCapped", {
        capped: true,
        size: 1e6
    })

/* io socket.io  Server instance */

collection
        .then(db => io.adapter(createAdapter(db)))
        .catch(error => {
            /* Collection already exists */
           if (error.code == 48) {
               io.adapter(createAdapter(mongoose.connection.collection("chatCapped")))
               return;
           } 
           console.log(error)
        })
```

mongoose setup code

```js
const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ChatApp?retryWrites=true'

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}, (error, _db) => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log(`MongoDB  Connected!!`);
})

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it seems that you would have to use 2 connections.

If you check the code of [socket.io-adapter-mongo](https://github.com/modit/socket.io-adapter-mongo/blob/master/index.js), it seems they are using [mubsub](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub) to establish the connection to mongo, so I don't think there is a way to only use one connection without altering the libraries.